# Is all code compiled and included on the final binary?

Tags: class, compilation, binary

Suppose I create a class extension with hundreds of methods and I include that class in my project.

Now suppose that from that extension, I just use 2 or 3 methods. Remember that the class extension has hundreds of methods.

When I compile the code, what will be included in the binary?

Will it be just the methods I have used from that class extension or all of them, including the ones that were not used by that particular project?

Comment: Depends on whether you use static or dynamic linking. In dynamic linking, only used symbol names will be included. In static linking, if you use option like `--no-whole-archive`, only used `.o` files will be included. Otherwise, whole `.a` file will be included. Also note that not only the methods you directly use/override will be called. This also is about vtables and stuff.

Comment: thanks. please make this an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be divided into three categories:

- Dynamic (shared) linking
- Static linking, `--whole-archive` in GNU ld
- Static linking, `--no-whole-archive` in GNU ld

(other linkers might have similar options).

## Dynamic linking

The code will only include the method names from the library you are extending.

## Static linking, whole archive

Oops... whole code of the other class will be included.

## Static linking, no whole archive

Only the object files you use will be included. I suggest that, for large classes, you split the source code wherever possible.

## Used methods

Despite the methods you explicitly use, each extending/override will require some symbols like `vtable`. Refer to your compiler documentation.

Comment: sorry for the delay on accepting this. THANKS for the answer.